# Как с помощью CSS повернуть текст против часовой стрелки на определенный градус?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как с помощью CSS добиться такого же эффекта, как на картинке: повернуть текст на 45 градусов против часовой стрелки?

Comment: rotate(a) a-угол

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Comment: [дубликатов-то](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D+transform+rotate)

Answer (score 1):

Прочитайте про css свойство [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/transform). Конкретно этот случай будет решён так:

```css
.text {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="text">2021</div>
```